# Как проверить электронную подпись PDF-файла используя Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, криптография, цифровая-подпись

Как проверить валидность ЭЦП PDF-документа с помощью Python? (SIG-файл имеется)

Comment: SIG, значит отсоединенная. по госту?

Answer (score 0):

Наверное так:

````
# Открываем PDF-документ
pdf_file = open('test.pdf', 'rb')
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)

# Получаем объект подписи
sig_file = open('test.sig', 'rb')
sig_data = sig_file.read()

# Проверяем подпись
if pdf_reader.isEncrypted:
    pdf_reader.decrypt('')
sig_obj = pdf_reader.signature
if sig_obj and sig_obj.verify(sig_data):
    print('Подпись верна')
else:
    print('Подпись неверна')```
````

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]